# How to make div clickable after refreshing a section with ajax?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I would like to ask a slightly abstract question. Maybe there is someone who can help me.
I want to update a section of the html page with Ajax after clicking on the div with class `update` or `delete`.

```
$('.update').on('click',function(){
        $.post(ajaxurl, content, function(data){
            $('.data-section').html(data);
        });
    });
```

`data` contain multiple blocks of `menu`, hence many clickable div `Update` and `Delete`.

```
<div class="data-section">
<div class="menu">
    <div class="Update">
        Update
    </div>
    <div class="Delete">
        Delete
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I refresh that section with ajax, no div of that section work afterwards. I have to refresh the page for the div to work again. Is this a usual behaviour?  How can I manage this problem?

Comment: Where are the buttons in your html? I see no .btn-event DOM object @Kyv

Comment: I have updated the question @DankyiAnnoKwaku. Thank you for pointing that out. Indeed, they are buttons as well, but I did not include them. They have the same behavior as the clickable div.

Comment: It sounds like the linked duplicate describes the problem, right?  You replace the content of the `div`, so any event handlers you had for elements in that div will no longer work - those elements are gone.  See the answers in the dup - eg `$('.data-section').on('click', '.update', function() { ...`.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you.